# How to design a parallel-able lab power supply?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, parallel, series

I want to design a power module that can be configured in series or parallel if the power sources are isolated.

The problem is I don't know how to implant master/slave function, at first I was thinking to add a diode to the output of each supply but then I can't compensate for the diode voltage drop because moving the feedback after the diode is point less.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo6mZY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How the power supplies in the market do it? do they disconnect the slave op amp output and drive the slave transistor with the master op amp?

Can someone please explain how master/slave in lab power supplies works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When paralleling supplies (assuming that the outputs of both are close to each other), a small amount of resistance needs to be added between supplies. Why?

No supply is perfect and small variations *in voltage* or voltage offsets can cause current to move from one supply circuit to the next. (for example, even if you set both circuits to 10V, one may be outputting 10.1V and the other 10V from amplifier offsets and component variability) The offsets lead to problems with the paralleled circuits not sourcing current evenly, and could lead to instability or overheating among other problems.

> How the power supplies in the market do it?

What you have above is somewhat like an LDO (Linear Dropout Regulator). The way that you parallel those is with resistors between them.

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/paralleling-linear-regulators-made-easy.html

There are also schemes that are more related to switching circuits which have a [master/slave control loop](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-parallel-DC-DC-Buck-Converters_fig1_281847065). Also keep in mind when paralleling switching circuits one also needs to worry about syncing or not syncing the feedback loops so they don't interfere with each other.

Note:
One problem in the diagram above is the voltage is different on each supply circuit (one being 5V and one being 10V) which would cause issues for the circuit (so you may want to change the diagram).

Comment: There's a 100m ohm resistor on the high side (shunt resistor), is that enough? but how those power supplies switch to parallel with a switch?

Comment: Where is the switch in the circuit? (between circuits, on the output or the input?) As far as the shunt resistor goes, I usually run calculations worst case, you want the drop across the resistors to be similar to the worst case voltage difference between the supplies, but at the same time you also need to consider current and heating through the resistors.

Comment: [This PSU](https://siglent.co.uk/product/siglent-spd3303x-2x-0-32v-3-2a-2-5v-3-3v-5-0v-3-2a-220w-programmable-dc-power-supply-copy/) for example, switches to series or parallel with a switch. How do the master slave function works?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like a UCC39002 that's designed to interface with a power supply's remote sense terminals.  Multiple units are connected together with a bus that sets the target average current output.